# mysql left join if row doesnt exist, use 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to get a list of dates for a tables with the avg engagement rate. But at the moment it is skimming dates from the list if they dont exist in the media table. So if the row doesnt exist, i would like the engagement rate to be 0.

for example (currently)

```
2017-09-30 - 123
2017-09-28 - 1234
2017-09-27 - 12345
```

etc

but it should be

```
2017-09-30 - 123
2017-09-29 - 0
2017-09-28 - 1234
2017-09-27 - 12345
```

here is my query

```
"select d.date AS created_at,
                AVG((IFNULL(v.likes, 0) + IFNULL(v.comments, 0)) /
                IFNULL((SELECT count FROM followers prev WHERE DATE(prev.created_at) = DATE(v.created_at)
                                                  AND prev.profile_id = '".$this->profile->id."'
                                                  ORDER BY created_at
                                                  DESC LIMIT 1), 0) * 100)
                                                  AS count
                from
                (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) date from
                 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
                 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
                 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
                 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) d
                left join media v on d.date = DATE(v.created_at)
                where d.date between '".Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->startDate)->toDateTimeString()."' and '".Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->endDate)->toDateTimeString()."'
                AND v.profile_id = '".$this->profile->id."'
                group by d.date
                order by d.date DESC"
```

Comment: That's not a query, that's a string.

Comment: well im using laravel, but i didnt want to paste it all in

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Ah, so this cant be done using mysql then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get true `LEFT JOIN` result, move the table v condition from `WHERE` to `ON` clause:

```
        left join media v on d.date = DATE(v.created_at) AND v.profile_id = '".$this->profile->id."'
        where d.date between '".Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->startDate)->toDateTimeString()."' and '".Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->endDate)->toDateTimeString()."'
```

Comment: thanks so much! 

I thought you could only use AND in a WHERE clause